# Unknown index in a model theoretic considerations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, cardinals, index-notation

What is $k$ in $${}^kM$$ [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910158.pdf) on the page $11$ in the definition $2.10$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an instance of the standard notation ${{^A}B}$ for the set of maps from $A$ to $B$. Here $k\in\omega$, so it’s maps from $k$ to $M$, i.e., effectively $k$-tuples from $M$.

Comment: So it is not a typo interchanging $k$ with $\kappa$ ?

Comment: @user122424: Judging by the nearby material I don’t think so.

Comment: Can you please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3715997/lambda-d-model-homogenity) question of mine ?

Comment: @user122424: I’m going out now, but I’ll take a look later this evening. I make no guarantees, though: it’s been a good 45 years since I last did any model theory.

Comment: OK. It's a rather trivial and basic question though.