# $(\lambda,D)$-model homogenity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, cardinals

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910158.pdf) on the page $41$ in the definition $6.1(3)$
I do not follow where $D$ from $6.1(3)$ appears in the definition of $(\lambda,D)$-model homogenity
in $6.1(2)$. It appears in the first $2$ paragraphs in the definition $6.1$ but not in the $\lambda-$sequence-homogenity from $6.1(2)$ so that $D=D(M)$ in $6.1(3)$ makes sense via its appearance in item $6.1(2)$.

Comment: I feel like I misunderstand your question. 6.1(2) does not depend on $D$ at all, it is just a definition for what "$\lambda$-homogeneous" means. Then 6.1(3) combines this with saying that something is $(\lambda, D)$-homogeneous if it is $\lambda$-homogeneous (as defined in 6.1(2)) and we have $D(M) = D$. What this last bit means has been defined before 6.1(2).

Comment: @MarkKamsma So, is it true that $M$ is $\lambda$-homogenous iff it is $(\lambda,D(M))-$homogenous ? Please note that $M$ in $D(M)$ instead of pure $D$.

Comment: Yes, because then the second requirement is trivially satisfied. I believe the point of this definition is that we want to restrict to models only realising types in $D$.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Do you really mean that it is an equivalence: $M$ is $\lambda-$homogeneous if and only if $(\Longleftrightarrow)$ it is $(\lambda,D(M))-$homogeneous ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comments into an answer. First we fix some set $D$, which is a set of types (without parameters). For a model $M$ the notation $D(M)$ means the set of all types (without parameters) realised in $M$. So this has nothing to do with the $D$ we fixed before.

Definition 6.1 consists of three parts, which are as follows.

1. Here we define the class $K_D$. This is the class of all models $M$ such that $D(M) = D$. That is, the class of all models that only realise types in $D$.
2. This is the usual definition of $\lambda$-homogeneity. Roughly saying that any partial elementary map with small domain can be extended to any small set ("small" meaning $< \lambda$). The definition in the paper only talks about extending by one element at a time, but a simple induction construction shows we can extend the domain of that partial elementary map to any set of cardinality $< \lambda$. This definition has *nothing* to do with $D$ or $D(M)$ or any of that.
3. The definition of $(\lambda, D)$-homogeneous. The point here is that these are the homogeneous models in the class $K_D$ (from part 1). So a model $M$ is $(\lambda, D)$-homogeneous if it is $\lambda$-homogeneous (in the sense of part 2) and $D(M) = D$.

In particular if we would start with some model $M$ and pick $D = D(M)$ then such a model is $(\lambda, D)$-homogeneous precisely when it is $\lambda$-homogeneous. Because the second requirement (that $D(M) = D$) is then trivially satisfied.

---

The point of this construction is to only consider models that realise certain types. Put differently, we will only be interested in models that omit certain types (namely the types *not* in $D$). This is interesting when for example studying vector spaces. Let $T$ be the first-order theory of real vector spaces. That is, we have two sorts $F$ and $V$, and $T$ specifies that $F$ is a real closed field and $V$ is a vector space over $F$. Of course there will be models where $F$ is not (isomorphic to) the standard reals $\mathbb{R}$. We do not want to consider those models. So we would be interested in studying the class of models where $F \cong \mathbb{R}$.

We can do that as follows. Add a constant for every element of $\mathbb{R}$ to our theory and add all the formulas that those elements satisfy in $\mathbb{R}$ (also called the elementary diagram of $\mathbb{R}$). Consider the following partial type (where $x$ is of sort $F$):
$$
\Sigma(x) = \{x \neq r : r \in \mathbb{R} \}.
$$
Now let $D$ be the set of all types *not* containing $\Sigma$. Then $K_D$ will be the class of all real vector spaces. Because by construction we made sure that every model of contains at least a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ (by adding the elementary diagram of $\mathbb{R}$). Any model $M$ where $F$ is bigger than $\mathbb{R}$ will satisfy a type that contains $\Sigma$. So for such a model we have $D(M) \neq D$, and hence $M \not \in K_D$.